# Is it possible to use C++ with Unity instead of C#?

Tags: c++, unity

The title kind of says it all. Is it possible to replace C# with C++ on a game using Unity?

Comment: It is if you have the Pro edition. For more information see: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Plugins.html

Answer (score 28, accepted):

It is possible to use C++ with the Free version of Unity, although it is easier to work with if you have a Unity Pro license. All you have to do is wrap it up in a DLL and follow the instructions below on where to place it.

I wrote an article that covers this topic: **[Unity and DLLs: C# (managed) and C++ (unmanaged)](http://ericeastwood.com/blog/17/unity-and-dlls-c-managed-and-c-unmanaged)**

> For Unity 4 Free:
>
> - Add unmanaged code to the Unity Project Root: `UnityProject`
> - Add managed code to the Plugins folder: `UnityProject`->`Plugins`
> - When you build a project, copy the unmanaged code to `BuildRoot`->`Data`->`Plugins`
>
> For Unity 4 Pro and any Unity 5:
>
> - Just copy the DLLs into `UnityProject`->`Plugins`

Unmanaged means C++ and Managed means C#

Comment: Has this changed for Unity 5 where the free version contains all of the  engine features of the pro version?

Comment: @GeekyMonkey Updated the article and answer.

Comment: It makes no sense to try to replace C# with C++ in the Unity3D context. This answer may be helpful if interfacing with native code was asked for.

Comment: With the new IL2C++ technology, there aren't many reasons to use C++ instead of C#. Right now, it's limited to mobile platforms but expect the tech to soon be available on PC.

Comment: In the linked article, there is a comment near the start: "This guide really only applies to Unity 5- (Unity 4)". Reading the text directly before that comment, I might have thought to read: "This guide really only applies to Unity 5". Does anyone understand that comment?

Comment: @user2023370 I updated that part to make the language clearer "Unity 4 and below", thanks for the comment :)

Answer (score 4):

It is possible though inconvenient. You'd have to write managed C++ to achieve it. And yes, there is such thing as managed C++. Managed doesn't specifically mean C# and unmanaged C++. To achieve it you'll need to import UnityEngine DLL file. When you're finished you put it in the (Unity Project Name)/Plugins folder. Here would be the code you'd use: 
In the C++ file:

```
public ref class CPPUNITY {
  public:
     void Start() {
         Debug::Log("C++ printed message");
     }

};
```

In the C# file:

```
     using UnityEngine;
     public class FileName {
         void Start() {
              CPPUNITY.Start();
         }
     }
```

That exact code wouldn't work but thats a base.

Comment: Does the mono runtime used in Unity finally support mixed mode assemblies? We haven't had luck some years ago on 4 and assemblies from VS 2012 so this would be really great!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can use https://github.com/jacksondunstan/UnityNativeScripting

This is basically a code generator which allows you to write C++ code which calls generated C# bindings. Your C++ is then compiled to a binary "Unity plugin" which can be used in your game. Of course, the README of the above repository goes into a lot more detail.