# Using Unity/Unreal as graphic engine while programming the game externally

Tags: unity, unreal

My favorite language is C++ and I feel most comfortable to stick to it.

I made a game in C++ primarily using the console output as a graphical interface: somewhat like that of dwarf fortress.

However I wish to connect my game to either Unity or Unreal so that I can take advantage of their graphic rendering.

Is it possible? Running a game on other program while separately running an application on Unreal or Unity for rendering purpose? Or should I just make a game from ground up on Unreal or Unity?

Comment: See also [Is it possible to use C++ with Unity instead of C#?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/82518/is-it-possible-to-use-c-with-unity-instead-of-c).

Comment: @Theraot isn't it "shared library" dll? I am not building a library in c++ then wanting to use it. I made a fully functional game written on c++ that runs on its own using console as a graphical display. I want Unity or Unreal to "display" my game.

Comment: You will probably have to split your code such that all your UI code is isolated from the rest, so you can change it easily. Once you have done that, you might aswell make the rest a library that is called by an executable that has the UI... and that executable could be Unity. However, if you insist, see also [Is it possible to use the Unreal Engine as a big C++ library, without using the editor?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/100604/is-it-possible-to-use-the-unreal-engine-as-a-big-c-library-without-using-the).

Comment: @Theraot I do not want to make a library then run the game on Unity by calling the library. I want to run the game as a console application as it is. Then have a library to communicate between my game and the Unity/Unreal so that Unity/Unreal can express my game as a graphical display. I want to have all my game codes be done in c++ separately. Then have some library that Unity/Unreal can use to ask my game where monsters are and where players are, so that Unity/Unreal can display monsters and players. Then when user clicks the monster/player, I want Unity to talk back to my game

Comment: talk back to my game, that the player clicked monster/his-her-avatar.

Comment: You will still need some game-side hook to communicate with your C++ code. This can be very minimal, just an interface layer to ensure your DLL code can access all of the information it needs and perform all the actions you want. The game logic can remain wholly in your DLL if that's how you prefer to work.

Comment: I guess you need some [Inter-process communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) solution, perhaps using a dll (as in the first link posted) can help you accomplish that. I suppose it would be similar to having your game connect to a remote server (the client sends input to the server, the server tells the client what happens). However, I do not have experience in the particular of your case.

Comment: Ty. So I can either, have DLL that contains all my game logics and run it on Unity/Unreal. Or have some inter-process communication solution? I guess these two are the only choices I have.

Comment: This really isn't a duplicate question to the one linked.